# Javascript non-interfering time delay

Tags: javascript, time, delay, timedelay

I need a non-interfering time delay in javascript. Specifically, I need something like:

```
console.log("A");
someSortOfSleepFunction(3000);
console.log("B");
console.log("C");
```

with the three-second sleep actually occuring between "A" and "B", i.e.

```
A
wait
B
C
```

If I use:

```
console.log("A");
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("B"); }, 3000);
console.log("C");
```

what I get, of course, is:

```
A
C
wait
B
```

I wrote a sleep function, i.e.

```
function mdjSleep(n) {

    var sleepStart;
    var sleepEnd;
    var sleepNow;

    sleepStart = new Date().getTime();
    sleepEnd = sleepStart + n;

    while(true) {
        sleepNow = new Date().getTime();
        if (sleepNow >= sleepEnd) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

but it interferes, i.e., when I code:

```
console.log("A");
mdjSleep(3000);
console.log("B");
console.log("C");
```

instead of

```
A
wait
B
C
```

it produces:

```
wait
A
B
C
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Closest equivalent in js to what you're looking for is  [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Comment: Your `mdjSleep` function works actually. The only problem is that it blocks everything, including the buffered console from displaying the already logged `A` line.